# How to modify code in suitecrm from scratch using visual code

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to learn how to modify code in suitecrm , but i dont find a course(free if possible) , what is your sugestion or tips to learn more about this CRM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the best way to learn is by doing.

- First, you have to decide which version you want to learn. If you want to understand the suitecrm it is better to start with V6/V7. Because this versions are totally in PHP.
- SuiteCRM development guide is good enough for beginners. Yes, when you going to some modification out of the box then it won't be sufficient.
- They have every versions installation process.
- For help, SuiteCRM community forum is very helpful. Lot of contributors constantly help each others.
- For your help, I'm sharing some youtube video links which helps you to get started.
- [Getting Started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2su-fDfSTY)
- [Explaining the modules & walk-through of SuiteCRM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxEZT0IE3ew)
- [For when you want modify the system from the codes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_zR5AfXBwA&list=PLEgubq7z_3_shlAEtV9M_Il7Pv_c7P7iD&index=1)
- This videos helps me lot when I started

Answer (score 0):

These are few ways I modify the code, if needed, in SuiteCRM:

1. SuiteCRM User Guide:  this guide is well written and maps the way to learn about the system as a user and as a developer.
   https://docs.suitecrm.com/user
2. I joined the SuiteCRM Community:  Here I learn a lot of helpful information from developers who have been dealing with the same issues I encounter.
   https://community.suitecrm.com/invites/QtsSmkJLHW
3. I have studied the 215 database tables and recreated a map to understand how they are related to each other, the fields, properties and data types.
4. I am constantly mastering small skills: When I started the first challenge was making installations and upgrading by downloading the zip file from the SuiteCRM page. I did it over and over until I got it right.
5. I learnt about folders and files structures, permissions, backup, cron jobs, modules
6. I play with the code and try to understand how PHP and Angular is used.
7. Above all I am a user for my own business which creates the need to learn new functionalities.

Comment: Thank u for your recommendation, i really appreciate